# How can I get my Python to parse the following text?

Tags: python, ascii, python-unicode

I have a sample of the text:

```
"PROTECTING-ħarsien",
```

I'm trying to parse with the following

```
import csv, json

with open('./dict.txt') as maltese:
    entries = maltese.readlines()
    for entry in entries:
        tokens = entry.replace('"', '').replace(",", "").replace("\r\n", "").split("-")
        if len(tokens) == 1:
            pass
        else:   
            print tokens[0] + "," + unicode(tokens[1])
```

But I'm getting an error message

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `dict.txt` is UTF-8 encoded (`ħ` is `0xc4 0xa7` in UTF-8).

You should [open the file as UTF-8](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html), then:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('./dict.txt', encoding="utf-8") as maltese:
    # etc.
```

You will then have Unicode strings instead of bytestrings to work with; you therefore  don't need to call `unicode()` on them, but you may have to re-encode them to the encoding of the terminal you're outputting to.

Comment: I have tried this suggestion and I'm still getting the same error.  Is there anything else I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you re-encode the string to your terminal's encoding before outputting?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your last line to (this has been tested to work on your data):

```
print tokens[0] + "," + unicode(tokens[1], 'utf8')
```

If you don't have that `utf8`, Python assumes that the source is `ascii` encoding, hence the error.

See http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type